# libwiengine: Cannot open android adapter layer

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone

I have use `wiengine` jar file in my application, it works fine in `2.3 device` but not working in `4.2 device` .

Getting error

```
libwiengine: Cannot open android adapter layer
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: resolved issue by adding updated version 3.10.3 https://github.com/stubma/WiEngine#